# Replace non word related words with new line

Tags: java, string, replace

I already know how to remove the whitespace and non word related text from a inputed string

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\W","");
```

and for an assignment we received we have to take a sentence, like "I love Cheese--!" and turn it into something like this:

I

love

Cheese

My code is:

```
    String input = null;    // Used for a sentence input


    System.out.print("What'd You Say? ");
    input = TextIO.getlnString();    // retrieves users input

    input = input.replaceAll("\\W","\n");
    System.out.println("Wordenator Replies:\n" + input);
```

but it replaces all non character letters like "-, !, ., ^, etc." with a new line
So some of the text has many new lines and it ends up with large spaces of empty space if the text contains more than one non-character text in it.

How would I go about making the new lines only appear once per word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing *each* non-word character with a newline, try replacing all *runs* of non-word characters:

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\W+", "\n");
```

The `+` means "one or more" - that way, whether you encounter a single space or a string like "--!", you'll only get one newline.

I recommend reading up on regular expressions; they'll prove very useful in your programming life. I find [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) to be a helpful primer.

**Edit**

Do be warned, though, that this is a very simplistic approach to the problem of [*tokenization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization). If these are your specific requirements for an assignment, that's fine, but I'd recommend trying for extra credit by bringing up the question of "what *is* a word?" For the simplest example that comes to mind in this case, "don't" would be split into

```
don

t
```

Is that really what you'd want?

Comment: Better than my solution :-).

Answer (score 0):

From javadoc:

\W  A non-word character: [^\w]

You should use 2 replacements. First: replace all non characters with no sign, second replace all spaces with new line:

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^ &&[\\W]]", ""); //all non-space characters except space removed
input = input.replaceAll(" +", "\n"); //all spaces (one or more) replaced with new line
```